# Android Studio - import com.facebook.FacebookSdk is flagged as Unused Import Statement

Tags: android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've followed the Facebook Android QuickStart guide and added the code as required.  However in my **MainActivity.java** this line is greyed out:

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
```

Android Studio tells me this is an unused import statement.  I cannot fathom why, because it looks like all the other code is in place.

Running Android Studio 4.0

In Gradle Scripts | build.gradle I'm adding:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }
```

And then in Dependencies I'm adding:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6]'
```

Then I build the App [no errors] and add this in MainActivity.java:

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
```

But it's greyed out as an unused import.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I replaced the Dependencies entry with this:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3'
```

And it all works AOK.
I'm a newb!